# Change update insert attributes programmatically

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I would like to know if it's posible to change the insert and update attributes of a property defined in the mapping of a Class.
This is because in one scenario I need to update a property (or properties), but not in another, it's posible?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Lets say that I've the Class User(with name, surname and loginDate), when the user logs into the app, I need to update only loginDate. But the administrator of the system must be able to edit the name and the surname of the User. 
The only other solution that ocurrs to me is to use HQL for a Update (or in the worst case SQL), but I want if it's posible to modify that attributes.

EDIT 2: after reading Java persistence with hibernate and some forum threads I found that once the sessionFactory is created the mappings are immutables, and though You can change the properties programmatically, You need to create a new sessionFactory

Comment: Show this mapping, show some code, explain what you want to achieve with this code. If you don't want to update a property, don't update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// this is what the login screen calls
void updateLoginDate(Date date)
{
    User user = session.get(User.class);
    user.setDate(date);
    session.Flush();
}
```

and in the mapping you could specify `dynamicUpdate = true` on the class so that the generated sql only updates columns which have changed